# What is the opposite action of "You fought with your sister over the toy": "you sacrificed the toy for your sister."?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> **[fight](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fight_1?q=fight)** [intransitive, transitive] to struggle physically with somebody
>
> My little brothers are always fighting.
>
> He taught me how to fight with a sword.
>
> fight with somebody Riot police fought with demonstrators.
>
> He sometimes fights with other children in the playground.
>
> fight somebody She fought her attacker, eventually forcing him to
>   flee.
>
> fight over something Children will fight even over small things.
>
> dogs fighting over scraps of food
>
> fight somebody over something **They were fighting each other over a
>   toy.**
>
> fight (somebody) for something Paris offers to fight Menelaus for
>   Helen's hand.
>
> fight against somebody/something She fought hard against his strong
>   grip.

---

> **[sacrifice](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sacrifice_2)** [transitive] to give up something that is important or
>   valuable to you in order to get or do something that seems more
>   important for yourself or for another person
>
> sacrifice something for somebody/something She sacrificed everything
>   for her children.
>
> The designers have sacrificed speed for fuel economy.
>
> sacrifice something Would you sacrifice a football game to go out
>   with a girl?
>
> sacrifice something to something In her writing, clarity is sometimes
>   sacrificed to brevity.

---

The below picture shows that **the 2 children are fighting over the toy**

[image]

Now, how to express a child is willing to give up his toy for his sister when his sister wants that toy. It is the opposite action of the above one. Look at the picture

[image]

DO we say "**you sacrificed the toy for your sister.**"?

Comment: **Sacrifice** is rather a dramatic term to use in this context. I would say "You gave up the toy to your sister",  or "you let your sister have the toy".

Comment: @KateBunting, excellent, give something  up (to somebody), He gave up his seat to a pregnant woman (= stood up to allow her to sit down). (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/give-up?q=give+up). But, it seems the dictionary is not too clear. It should say "you are willing to give up things that you love / like & give it to one that needs because you want that person to be happy.

Comment: You might give something  up to another person for any number of reasons. They don't all have to be part of the definition.